# How to get verification code/change password code in boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pytest, boto, botocore, moto

I'm writing tests in Moto and Pytest for a confirm sign up route that receives a verification code and a email and uses boto method [confirm_sign_up](https://stackoverflow.comhttps://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp/client/confirm_sign_up.html) to confirm user.
My question is: After I created a user pool, a client and a user, how can I get the verification code that will be sended to the user e-mail?

I'm also creating tests for password change, that requires a code to change the user password. I also want to know how to get this password change code.

I looked for methods in boto and not discovered a method or attribute like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moto does not require a valid verification code for either `confirm_forgot_password` or `confirm_signup` - anything will do.

For `confirm_forgot_password`, there is a way to test expired confirmation codes.
The `forgot_password`-method will return a header specific to Moto, `x-moto-forgot-password-confirmation-code`, that contains a confirmation code in the format `moto-confirmation-code:...`.

If you pass a code to `confirm_forgot_password` that starts with `moto-confirmation-code:`, but does not match up with the code returned by the `forgot_password`-method, it will throw an error.

See the code here:
https://github.com/getmoto/moto/blob/2b0d6ee0dc333cc4a581abf8ed0d6ebf2afdc3ab/moto/cognitoidp/models.py#L1551C9-L1551C32

And internal tests that Moto uses for this scenario:
https://github.com/getmoto/moto/blob/2b0d6ee0dc333cc4a581abf8ed0d6ebf2afdc3ab/tests/test_cognitoidp/test_cognitoidp.py#L3124

Comment: Thank you very much! Where did you saw that? Is it in some part of documentation? And other related question: The same occurs for sign_up function? you can send any password and moto will validate?

Comment: I'm a maintainer for Moto, so insider info. :) There is no documentation on this (yet).

Comment: `confirm_signup` approves any and all confirmation codes